# Rails: Restarting the server each time make change in code using console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using accessing my controllers methods from console with rails c command. The problem I am facing is that each time I have reflect any changes made in the code then I have to first exit and restart . Is these any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you show which command you're exactly running to fetch the data in your console?

Comment: i am just calling static method of some class and this method prints the output on screen

Comment: reload! is not working as desired so that rules out that option

Comment: You need to tell exactly where you're facing the issue. It's not possible to help you with hit and trials, and assumptions.

Answer (score 5):

From your rails console, type `reload!`

```
2.1.2 :012 > reload!
Reloading...
 => true
2.1.2 :013 >
```

to reload all your Rails application code. No need to exit and start console again!

Comment: Yes, however there is this caveat: If you have any pre-existing objects, they will still be based on the previous code. So it's important to re-initialize any objects you are working with after a `reload!` command.

Comment: ^^ Exactly! + those objects will not have updated methods with the updated code and you may end up getting weird errors!

Answer (score 0):

If you have associations you can do this:

```
class home
  belongs_to :renter
end

class renter
  has_one :home
end
```

Let's say you start with home attributes:

```
home = Home.where(renter_id: 1)
  => #< Home id: 1, alarm: "no">
renter = Renter.find(1)
renter.home.alarm
  => "no"
```

Then you modify home:

```
home.alarm = "yes"
home.save
```

When you do:

```
renter.home
  => #< Home id: 1, alarm: "no">   # it still returns no
renter.home(true)
  => #< Home id: 1, alarm: "yes">"  
        # you can use (true) to make sure your association 
        # change is reflected, it basically queries the server again
```